# Binary search tree largest value

Tags: python, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to find the largest value in a binary search tree. The sample solution is given below, but I'm trying to understand if there's anything wrong with my solution? My problem with the sample solution is that it seems to check whether each node is not None twice: once in "if not current.right" and second in "while current ... current = current.right", which seems superfluous.

Sample solution:

```
      def find_largest(root_node):
        current = root_node
        while current:
            if not current.right:
                return current.value
            current = current.right
```

My solution:

```
      def find_largest(root_node):
        current = root_node
        if current:
            while current.right is not None:
                current = current.right
            return current.value
```

Question/Code source: Interviewcake.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is correct, the sample solution checks for `None` twice for each node and your solution checks only once, otherwise they are equivalent. I’d also say that your solution is more readable, but that’s somewhat subjective.

As an enhancement, you can get rid of the first line in the body of your function, by calling the argument of the function `current` instead of `root_node`. It gives you an extra benefit as now the argument name doesn’t suggest that your function can be called only with the *root* node as an argument. Indeed, it correctly finds the largest value in any subtree.

Comment: Is there a reason for his if current:? The sample doesn't check that. Yes, he consolidated the while and subsequent if not. So... a faster way that used more memory might be to assign a last value and just say while current.right last=current.right return last. Huh?

Comment: @joshstrike Of course there is a reason. What happens if `root_node` is `None` (that is, we are given an empty tree)?

Comment: @joshstrike It's not nice to label or call names.

Comment: @joshstrike Look around this site, it's peopled by polite helpers.

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks for your efforts to keep this website a polite place!